# Always displays error when i start the server 1.12.2 on Magma (Forge)

Tags: java, server, minecraft, minecraft-forge

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bzCW.png)

I dont really know how to fix this, i have launched before this but now i changed the mods and plugins and this is now working, maybe is it due to mods and plugins? (Mods probably not, because i removed all mods that not worked.)

````java
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_282-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.282-b08, mixed mode)
:/home/container$ java -Xms128M -Xmx2048M -Dterminal.jline=false -Dterminal.ansi=true -jar server.jar
Starting Magma
Checking for new version...
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 502 for URL: https://ci.hexeption.dev/job/Magma%20Foundation/job/Magma/job/master/lastSuccessfulBuild/api/json
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1900)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:268)
at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1068)
at org.magmafoundation.magma.downloads.MagmaUpdater.versionChecker(MagmaUpdater.java:52)
at net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.ServerLaunchWrapper.main(ServerLaunchWrapper.java:62)```

update (i disabled auto-update but its doing nothing.)
````

Answer (score 0):

The given URL (`https://ci.hexeption.dev/job/Magma%20Foundation/job/Magma/job/master/lastSuccessfulBuild/api/json`) is not accessible. It return error 502.

The URL is to check about latest version. Such as explained in the last line, it failed to make auto-update.

This error doesn't change something, you can't just don't know if it's the latest version.

To fix it you should download new version on [their github](https://github.com/magmafoundation/Magma), where you will find the [new API link for updated checking](https://api.magmafoundation.org/api/resources/magma/1.12/dev/latest).